# Resolving the issue with closing or using red tag?

Tags: discussion, support, per-site-meta, bug-reports

What's the correct approach to resolve old questions tagged with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) which are no longer reproducible?

Should they be closed with the reason:

> The problem described here can no longer be reproduced. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.

or just tagged by a moderator with [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)?

Comment: I think closing them is fine, that will in some cases schedule them for deletion. I think we should reserve [tag:status-norepro] for those cases where a dev investigated and was unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Side note: I retracted my close vote on that search question, as I was wrong about its status.

Comment: Also least here - the mods tend to leave most status tags except review mostly for staff use. They have insight into what's actually up more than any of us. Closure seems like a less blunt instrument

Answer (score 4):

Both options (closing and tagging as [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)) serve the same purpose: marking the bug report as 'finished', i.e. not needing any further response. The advantage of closing is that the community can do it without needing help from ♦ moderators or Stack Exchange staff.

That said, most per-site metas **don't have** the close reason you describe, presumably because bug reports like that are quite rare; most users post them here on Meta Stack Exchange anyway, or on Meta Stack Overflow, which is the only site I know of to have the close reason as well. Of course, you could still type it as a custom off-topic reason...

Comment: Good catch for "per-site metas reason"!